# defined in discarded section

Tags: c++, boost, mpi

The following is my current environment

- Boost version - 1.55
- Cmake - 2.8
- Ubuntu - 12.04
- g++ - 4.8
- MPI - 1.8.1
- BLAS/LAPACK - Intel MKL

When I compile my Boost MPI code in the above settings, I am getting the following error.

```
`.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_3mpi9exceptionEED2Ev' referenced in section `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_3mpi9exceptionEED1Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_3mpi9exceptionEED1Ev]' of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_mpi.a(broadcast.o): defined in discarded section `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_3mpi9exceptionEED2Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_3mpi9exceptionEED5Ev]' of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_mpi.a(broadcast.o)
`.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_17bad_function_callEED2Ev' referenced in section `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_17bad_function_callEED1Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_17bad_function_callEED1Ev]' of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.a(cmdline.o): defined in discarded section `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_17bad_function_callEED2Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_17bad_function_callEED5Ev]' of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.a(cmdline.o)
`.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEED2Ev' referenced in section `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEED1Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEED1Ev]' of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.a(value_semantic.o): defined in discarded section `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEED2Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEED5Ev]' of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.a(value_semantic.o)
`.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorISt11logic_errorED2Ev' referenced in section `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorISt11logic_errorED1Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorISt11logic_errorED1Ev]' of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.a(convert.o): defined in discarded section `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorISt11logic_errorED2Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorISt11logic_errorED5Ev]' of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.a(convert.o)
`.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_9iostreams10gzip_errorEED2Ev' referenced in section `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_9iostreams10gzip_errorEED1Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_9iostreams10gzip_errorEED1Ev]' of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_iostreams.a(gzip.o): defined in discarded section `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_9iostreams10gzip_errorEED2Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_9iostreams10gzip_errorEED5Ev]' of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_iostreams.a(gzip.o)
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [factor] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/factor.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Browsing the internet I figured the following solutions and none of them works.

1. Having the latest of all the software compiler, libraries, cmake etc. I have the latest. But I still have the problem.
2. Include -fexceptions and -fno-use-linker-plugin. I am still getting the error with my current linker command as follows. 
   `/usr/bin/mpicxx -fexceptions -fno-use-linker-plugin CMakeFiles/factor.dir/factor.cpp.o CMakeFiles/factor.dir/factor_jobs.cpp.o  -o factor -rdynamic -L/home/ramki/libraries/armadillo-4.300.0/usr/lib -L/home/ramki/intel/mkl/lib/intel64 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_mpi.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_iostreams.a -lboost_serialization -lboost_iostreams -lboost_program_options -lboost_mpi -llapack -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_sequential -lpthread -lm -lz -larmadillo factorization/libfactorization.a -Wl,-rpath,/home/ramki/libraries/armadillo-4.300.0/usr/lib:/home/ramki/intel/mkl/lib/intel64`
3. Change the order of the linking libraries - Even this didn't help.

Let me know what is the mistake and how to resolve this error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unusual C++ linker error - 'Defined in discarded section'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811503/unusual-c-linker-error-defined-in-discarded-section)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I uninstalled Boost1.43 to move to Boost1.55, some files of Boost1.43 were left in /usr/lib directory as well. The new libraries of Boost1.55 are installed in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu. While linking if /usr/lib is in the path before /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, then there is a change of boost1.43 libraries getting mixed up with Boost1.55. I deleted the older Boost1.43 files from /usr/lib and these problems got resolved. Remember to include /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu in the lib path during compilation.